# JavaDB Embedded

Tags: java, database, javadb

I have looked at and followed many tutorials, reviewed a couple of entries on stack overflow but I still don't understand if this is or even if what I am looking for actually exists.

**I want to know if it is possible to create a JAVA Application whose associated database might be stored and distributed within the same JAR or at least the same folder as the application such that the user does not need to install anything other than java, and is what i am describing called an Embedded JavaDB.**

If anyone could provide a link to a tutorial using NETBEANS 8.0 I would be much grateful. Thank You.

Comment: [HyperSonic SQL](http://hsqldb.org/) and [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) are both pure Java Database which can operate in single user/standalone/embedded modes

Comment: Is this a static database or something? You probably wouldn't want to modify records in a database that's packaged in the jar, right? If you want a database in memory (which would clear out every time you quit the program) you could use HSQLDB or H2. Could you provide a little more detail on your use case?

Comment: @nickgroenke What I am looking for is a simpler way do distribute the database. I want a persistent database (I don't want it to clear out every time i quit the program), but I don't want my app's final user having to install and configure any database server or to manually create and locally link the database to the app in order to run the app... Is it possible?

Comment: You could use SQLite, which stores the data in a file on disk. No setup is required from the end user. http://sqljet.com/tutorial.html

Comment: Databases are (very roughly said) a well administrated and protected memory segment... So the idea I have of an app running a JavaDB Embedded Database is one that only requires JDK (JRE) to run it's Jar and use a special segment (within the diet folder maybe) to run seamlessly wherever you want to copy paste the app folder. Am I just delirious and... If I am... what is then an Embedded database (just out of curiosity)?.... I'll check out that SQLite recommendation...

Comment: @nickgroenke What happens to the SQLite Database once I delete my app from wherever i have it? Is it also deleted or does it remains and have to be manually removed?

Comment: @AlexisRustamDevitre: Databases are not a well protected memory segment.  Unless you mean using JavaDB with the memory driver.  Nothing is going to read and write a DB to your Jar file.  It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @markspace That's why I said "very roughly speaking"... I don't need it to be in my Jar File (Which probably makes no sense at all) but i want to distribute it as seamlessly as a jar can be just copy pasted around. I still wonder if that i possible as i'm looking into SQLite...

Comment: Here's a link to the [JavaDB tutorial for NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html)  But the DB will remain after you delete the Jar file.  You have to use some sort of uninstaller to remove files that get created as the program runs.